# How can I import the package from the SQL Server Integration Services catalog?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm beginner in SSIS, the server has SQL Server installed and inside that, thre is a simple SSIS deploy package as seen here:

[image]

On the client, I installed the SSIS data tools and try too import that package to my data flow, right click on the SSIS package on the solution explorer and select the add existing package option, but in that window can not find SQL Server package, this image show that:

[image]

How can I import SQL Server package into SSIS? Thanks all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to your first picture, you are storing packages in so called SSIS Catalog store. Adding packages to existing SSIS Visual Studio solution is possible only for packages stored in MSDB - this is the SSIS 2008 way.
In SSIS 2012+ you can add complete project from SSIS and then - copy corresponding project from it.
Go to solution in the Visual Studio Solution Explorer, and choose **Add New Project**, then choose **Business Intelligence -> Integration Services -> Integration Services Import Wizard**
[image]
You can configure Path and Name of project being imported.
Hit OK and you will see Select Source window. Select SSIS server name and project inside this server, as shown below. 
[image] 
Hit OK to confirm import, and in a few steps you are done. Then you can try to move packages between projects.